# How to Edit a TextBox in a Notepad File?

Tags: vb.net, textbox, edit, notepad

I am building a small desk app in VB.net (Visual Studio) and I am struggling on this..

I want to edit a textbox in a notepad file. The file opens and saves on the Desktop of my PC but when I write something on the textbox it is not sent to the notepad. The notepad remains blank...
In the code below is what I've got so far.

```
Private Sub BtnEditQuestion_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnEdiPla.Click
    MsgBox("Now, a notepad will be openned. Edit the question on the file.")
    Dim desktop_path As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
    Dim writer As TextWriter = New StreamWriter(ruta_escritorio + "\planteamiento.txt")
    writer.Write(TxtPla.Text)
    Process.Start(desktop_path + "\planteamiento.txt")
End Sub
```

(I have also another button that will ask the user to upload the text file so the textbox fills with its content... if someone know to do both jobs in one button would be great too)

Comment: `txtBox.Text =  = File.ReadAllText(path)`; no?

Comment: Assuming that `ruta_escritorio` is the same as `desktop_path` (you probably just forgot to *translate* it), when you open the file in Notepad (assuming Notepad is the default editor of `.txt` files: it's not in my machine, for example), Notepad reads the entire content in memory. It doesn't read the text from a Stream. If it did, it would lock the Stream: you wouldn't be able to *update* the file content anyway. You can achieve this *behavior* using UI Automation or using `SendMessage` to send a `WM_SETTEXT` message to Notepad's `Edit` child control.

Comment: Also, you should really declare the StreamWriter with a Using statement: `Using writer = New StreamWriter(...) (...you write, it flushes...) End Using Process.Start(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  `txtBox.Text = = File.ReadAllText(path)`

Comment: this looks identical to one of the comments above. how does your answer improve on that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really want to display the file in your program and in notepad all in one event. If the user wants to edit it in your program you need 2 separate events.

I used the `File` object from `System.IO`. Streams need to be closed and disposed. `.ReadAllText` and `.WriteAllText` will open and close the file for you.

```
Private PathToFile As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) & "\planteamiento.txt"

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(PathToFile) 'File must exist
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    MsgBox("Now, a notepad will be openned. Edit the question on the file.")
    File.WriteAllText(PathToFile, TextBox1.Text)
    Process.Start(PathToFile)
End Sub
```

If you want to see changes made in notepad, the file will have to be saved in notepad and Button1 clicked again in your program to see changes.